# What are the options to parse and insert thousands of rows from data fetch

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I'm building a cache updater to cache some blockchain data in a local postgresql database. I made a node js script using node-postgres. Once I've fetched all the data, I do a for in loop to parse and insert it one row at a time.

I did a test with 2000 rows that took 5 min to retrieve, parse and insert. Everything went well but I might have way more entries in the future.
Normally, I should only have this full sync once at the beginning, then a cron job updating new entries every 5 seconds.

Since the local db will have regular back up, in best case if a problem occurs I could just reimport past local backup and sync missing entries from there only. In case something goes wrong though and a full sync needs to be redone with maybe 20 or 40 000 rows, is this still a valid option to do one row at a time in loop? I understand it would probably take 1 hour or more but it's only for the worst case scenario, so time is not a problem. Or is there better way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to group INSERT's by 10,100 rows on one INSERT query (PostgreSQL can do this)

Comment: Yes, don't do it one row at a time. Also take a look at the `COPY` command (but that can't do "only missing" afaik)

Comment: The first thing to establish is where your time is being taken up. Run some timing to see what each of the fetch/parse/insert is contributing to the cost. I would suspect that the parse/insert stages are where the most time is being taken. Also you don't mention if each `INSERT` is being done in a separate transaction or not. If it is, moving the transaction to cover all the inserts would improve things. This in addition to suggestions above.

Comment: Thanks everyone, i believe the parsing with reduce function is what take most of the time because there is only 1 fetch and the parse/insert start when he is done, i will run some test with timer and come back. Its running but would like to optimize, im not sure what "if each insert is done in a separate transaction" mean, im bit new to it, i use node-postgres pool and do simple client.query('INSERT INTO table... etc each loop iteration. What is advantage of transactions over queries? Is it like i do a BEGIN before the loop, all query in the loop and COMMIT at the end in a single request?

Comment: I did a test with 35 entries, fetching the data took 409ms, parsing them took 4.5ms and  looping over them with one by one insert took 4600ms. So i guess i clearly needs optimize the insertions.

Comment: I did a test on the 2000 tx again, with and without transactions and its actually quite the same: regular query : 4.07656667 Min and transactions :  3.97166667 Min so i guess it doesnt really matter which option. Difference is nothing is inserted if any error with transactions rollback right?